# Canpaigns tracking

Tags: tracking, campaigns

Please, can someone explain me how is the best approach (flow) to track marketing campaigns originated from different sources?

For instance, we create one landing page for each campaign and want to track the traffic on our main website which comes from each landing page.

I've heard something about using UTM parameters, but really don't know how it works.

I appreciate if someone can give an idea.

Cheers,

Tiago

Comment: Tracking campaigns is a very big subject.   A full answer to this question cannot possibly fit in a few paragraphs here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good explanation about UTM source for URLs.

https://neilpatel.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-using-utm-parameters/

for example

https://example.com/?utm_source=Landinpage1&utm_medium=Header

That means user come from your landingpage1 from the link which was given in the header section.